# Hyperbole language

Tags: writing, writing-style

I received feedback from my tutor saying that my use of “in other words” was hyperbole. My understanding of hyperbole is that it’s exaggerated language. How is “in other words” an exaggeration?

Comment: Better fit at https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @corey979 even there, the question would benefit from an example of the use of the phrase...

Comment: If you don't understand your feedback from your tutor, they're much better placed than we are to explain what they meant.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I sent him an email but he never replied back

Comment: @SolarMike sorry didn’t know about the ‘English’ section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't an exaggeration. Maybe they misused hyperbole because it contains "hyper-" and meant that "in other words" is excessive. In other words, maybe they want you to be more concise, since every time you use that phrase you're just repeating yourself (sort of).